# CRM Error administrator cant go to the solution

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

[This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTjTJ.jpg*)

The rest of the description:

- There were some changes made on the mobile version of the app,
- adfs was installed and set to ifd claim base authentication,
- There were also changes on site map.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you corrupted your site map (or whoever made the edits corrupted your site map).

The only way I know how to fix this particular error is through XRM Toolbox, Sitemap Editor plugin.

You will need to get the Sitemap XML from a different CRM instance that has all of the same customizations and MSFT solutions installed (Dev or Test should suffice).  Once you have that Site Map XML, copy and paste it into your "Corrupt" sitemap XML, and save/publish the changes from XRMTB.  You should be back in business.